# How to display reload text in iOS-Charts?

Tags: ios, swift, reload, ios-charts

I am using the Charts cocoa pod to display a line chart. When the user changed an option I need to update the chart. Depending on the selection, this can take 1-2 seconds. Therefore, I want to display a text that the chart is updating. Is there any option available to do this using the charts package?

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reloading text or so called `toast`, `progress`, you can find many open source projects for it.

I used to use `toast`, but also there is a famous one `https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD`

This is NOT about Charts library itself, so don't tag ios-charts.